# UART permissible cable length

Tags: uart, serial, digital-communications, esp32, serial-bus

I am communicating between two esp32's. Can the UART at a baudrate of 512000, work fine over a distance of 1 metre? . The data will be sent at 10ms intervals. Wires are standard 24 awg.

Comment: Can you just test it?

Comment: I could but that would mean removing alot of pre-existing wires.

Comment: Depends a lot on the intimate details of the wiring, how electrically noisy your environment is, your voltage levels, etc... You'd be much safer using tranceivers of some sort to drive the cable and receive.

Comment: the environment is not noisy, i am using clean dc signals. At max there would be pwm signals in the long wires nearby..i can lower the baud rate if it alleviates the problem or use twisted cables..

Answer (score 2):

It should work,

Parallel hard drives went to tens of millions of symbols per second on 0.05" pitch ribbon cables at about that scale.

they were using interspersed ground and signal wires to reduce cross-talk.

Comment: Yes, cheap dsub9 double shield cables, @ 9k6n81 can go 120 feet or longer, and the higher freq the shorter. You can shift up 3V3/5V0 to +- 12V using cheap Maixm chip, also you can add parity checks and resend if necessary. I usually start with 9k6bd, and use a scope to watch TxD/RxD waveform distortion as I add more and more dirt cheap dsub9 2m segments.

Comment: can this be achieved via bjts/mosfets ? one on the sender side and other on the reciever?

Comment: I guess so, it you're not worried about wasting energy (and making heat) but a 1m cable is short enough to not need that.